# Integrate $\operatorname{PV}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\tan(\pi x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, special-functions

A friend of mine send me the problem to integrate

> $$\operatorname{PV}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\operatorname{tan}(\pi x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$ where $\operatorname{PV}$ is *Cauchy  principle value*.

I'm getting $\frac{1}{2}\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)$ which is complex trigamma argument however, he has got answer in real closed form $\frac{\pi^2}{(e^{-\pi}+e^{\pi})^2.}$.

**My work**

I evaluted integral as follows

Recalling the result to due *Weiestrass factorization theorem*
$$ \operatorname{cos}(\pi x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4 x}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$$ taking $\log$ and differentiating with rest to $x$ we have  $$\operatorname{tan}(\pi x)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x}{(2n+1)^2-4x^2}$$ and thus subbing   this result the integral, we have $$\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2dx}{((2n+1)^2-4x^2)(1+x^2)^2}$$

Making partial fraction  and integration gives us $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2}{(2n+2i+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\psi^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)$$

As the per [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2Real+part+Digamma%281%2C1%2F2%2Bi%29) $$\Re\frac{1}{2}\left(\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{(e^{-\pi }+e^{\pi})^2}\tag{1}\label{mainfm}$$

My question is, *How do i prove the relation \eqref{mainfm}?*

I tried for the references of relationship between hyperbolic function and trigamma function however,  I cannot get any such relationship.

Any sort of help/ reference or different approches will be appreciated. Thank you.

Interestingly,  making change of $\operatorname{tan}(\pi x)$ as $\operatorname{tanh}(\pi x)$ I came up with the following  closed form

> $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\tanh(\pi x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(1)$ follows immediately from the "conjugation property" and the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function#Recurrence_and_reflection_formulae) for $\psi^{(1)}$:
$$\psi^{(1)}(\bar{z})=\overline{\psi^{(1)}(z)};\qquad\psi^{(1)}(z)+\psi^{(1)}(1-z)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi z}.$$

Comment: Thank you, @metamorphy, I'm wasn't aware of conjugate property. :)